# Rails: Find if server has libvips or other package installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm moving my application files to an ActiveStorage solution and would like to take advantage of its image interpolation functions (resize, crop, etc).

I have about 100+ application instances that stands on about 30 servers. Not all have the `libvips` or the `imagemagick` package installed, so I would like to add the `variant` method only if that lib is present. For example something like:

```rb
if has_my_server_libvips? 
  logo_header = Portal.logo_header.variant({ resize_to_fit: [230, 50] })
else
  logo_header = Portal.logo_header
end
```

Is there any Ruby / RoR built-in / custom method to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if these libraries have executable command. This is just idea, you can implement it as you wish

```
logo_header =
  if %i[vips magick].any? { |command| `which #{command}`.present? } 
    Portal.logo_header.variant({ resize_to_fit: [230, 50] })
  else
    Portal.logo_header
  end
```

`which command` returns path of executable bin (with new line character in the end) or empty string if absent

---

You can also define such method (for example in `Kernel`)

```rb
module Kernel
  def command_exists?(command)
    command = command.delete('^a-zA-Z')

    !`which #{command}`.empty?
  end
end
```

**But be careful: sanitize argument before call this method to prevent injection!**

Comment: Thanks. I've found that imagemagick on a Debian based server responds to `convert` and not to `magick`